# How to implement OAuth2 in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want my Rails application to act as an OAuth2 provider.

I am relatively new to Ruby development, however it seems to me that developing OAuth2 in Ruby in simple.

I saw many OAuth2 liberary in the web, but don't know how to implement in Rails project.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you could be more specific about what you are trying to achieve. I assume you want to authorise users using Oauth2 using Google or Facebook for example

I can recommend the Devise gem.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

which can be used to authorise through many providers such as facebook

https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook

or Google

https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2

UPDATE

Instructions for facebook auth

Add the Gem to your Gemfile

```
gem 'devise'
```

and from the command line run:

```
bundle install
```

then run the following commands

```
rails generate devise:install

rails generate devise user

rake db:migrate
```

where user is the model you are going to store user information in

You will need to add a few fields to your model

```
rails generate migration add_columns_to_user email:string provider:string
rake db:migrate
```

Then create a facebook app as you will need the App ID and secret key to authorise users

I add this to config/initializers/constants.rb

```
APPID = 'YOUR_APP_ID'
FBKEY = 'YOUR_FB_KEY'
```

add the following code to config/initializers/devise.rb

```
require 'devise/orm/active_record'
require "omniauth-facebook"
config.omniauth :facebook, APPID, FBKEY
```

add the following code to the bottom of config/routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

Ensure the devise has not added another devise_for route, delete if there is already a route present in routes.rb and add the code above

add the following code to your app/models/user.rb file

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
     :omniauthable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :email,  :provider, :uid, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me


def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
  user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
  unless user
    user = User.create(  provider:auth.provider,
                       uid:auth.uid,
                       email:auth.info.email,
                       password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                       )
  end
  user
end
```

in app/controllers add a directory called users

mkdir users

then add a file omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb with the following code to users dir

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

add the following code to your view

```
<% if current_user%>
  <%= current_user.email %>
  <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>
<% end%>
```

Comment: How to use device gem for authentication , can you show some step-by-step implementation.

Comment: I've done my best to add implementation to answer, my example is for authorising with facebook

Comment: Thanks for the above work.....Your example is for authorising with FB ,here FB is generating APPID and FBKEY,is it possible for my app to generate appid  and secret fey using device gem.

Comment: You will need to create a facebook app to authorise with facebook. see for more information http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/#step1

Comment: I am unsure about using other services such as google and twitter as I have not ever needed to authorise with these